# Data analysis for a one group pre/post test

Tags: panel-data, pre-post-comparison

I am measuring teachers' beliefs about education practices before and after a specific training workshop to determine if the workshop has a positive effect in changing teachers' beliefs towards reformed teaching practices. My problem is that I am unsure how to analyze the data. I can say that their beliefs were more traditional and then they were more reformed after the workshop based on a predetermined score range on the surveys. I can also calculate a percent change, but is that enough? Should I be doing another descriptive statistical test? All the ones I know of or can find compare groups or variables, but I only have one group and one variable. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are doing just fine. Better focusing on a smart descriptive presentation than on randomly picked statistical test. Please note that a hypothesis test is not 'descriptive'. Its about unknown parameters.

Answer (score 1):

For a score range (i.e. a continuous variable), you can use a [paired *t*-test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pairedt-Test.html), which will allow you to compare the mean, or average, score among teachers before and after the training workshop.

Using the free statistical program, R, you can use the below code to run a paired *t*-test:

`t.test(prescore,postscore,paired=TRUE) # where prescore is before; postscore is after`

If the resulting test generates a *p* value less than 0.05 (this seems to be an appropriate *p* value for this type of situation, correct me if I am wrong), then you can infer that there was a change in average score among teachers before and after the training workshop. Additionally, you can use the [confidence intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) to determine the magnitude of this change. Let me know if there is anything that I need to clarify!

Comment: This assumes a normal distribution for the differences and would only allow inference about the intervention (training workshop) if (1) there is no regression to the mean and (2) nothing else is changing at the same time (e.g., subjects getting better at being tested or subjects tiring).